# How many ways can 5 people sit at a round table such that none of them are sitting to the left of the first person they sat behind?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways can 5 people sit at a round table such that none of them are sitting to the left of the first person they sat behind?

Suppose we label each person with a number starting from $0$. We want to count all ways they can sit such that $0$ is never to the left of $1$, $1$ never to the left of $2$ and so on.

We know that there are $\frac{5!}{5}$ ways they can all sit down.

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle, we can correctly remove all the ways we don't want them sitting down.

If we count the number of ways $01$ are sitting next to each other, that would be $\frac{4!}{4}$ ways, likewise for $12$ sitting next to each other, and $23$, $34$, $40$. So the total amount of ways these pairs can sit next to each other is $5\frac{4!}{4}$

Likewise there are also $5$ cases for when $3$ people are sitting next to each other making $5\frac{3!}{3}$ the total.

There is also $5$ ways when $4$ people are sitting next to each other, giving us $5\frac{2!}{2}$ ways

And there is only one way where all $5$ people are sitting in a way we don't want them to.

So in total the number of ways should be: 
$\frac{5!}{5} - (5\frac{4!}{4} - 5\frac{3!}{3} + 5\frac{2!}{2} - 1) = 0$

But this doesn't match up with what I calculated which I believe is $8$ total ways.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you take into account the situation that `0` is sitting behind `1` while at the same time `1` is sitting behind `2`?  Did you treat this the same or differently than the situation that `0` is sitting behind `1` while `2` is sitting behind `3`?

Comment: Do you mean "beside" instead of "behind"?  Even with this substitution, I still can't make sense of the question.

Comment: @sasquires replace the word with "to the left of" instead.

Comment: @JMoravitz I believe I counted that correctly in the case where we have $5\frac{3!}{3}$. This counts 3 consecutive numbers sitting next to each other, and there are 5 cases of this happening.

Comment: @jd94 You counted the five cases `012`,`123`,...,`401`, which in more words you have something like `012` is just shorthand for saying `01` and `12`.  But, you neglected to account for things like `01` and `23` or `01` and `34`.  You should be careful with counting like this though since it is circular.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok, what does this clause mean?  "the first person they sat behind"

Comment: Never mind, I think I get it now.  We imagine that they all sit down at the table once and number them 0, 1, etc.  Then we imagine that they sit down again and every person must have a different neighbor to the left.

Comment: @sasquires obviously, our five people were originally sitting at the table initially... they are then given the numbers 0,1,...,4.  They then get up from the table, mix themselves up and want to sit back down at the table such that they are sitting in such a way so as to never be to the left of the same person that they were initially and we want to count how many ways they can do so.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay, so I notice that there are 5 ways for two consecutive numbers to be paired. Then there are also $5 \choose 2$ ways for two pairs of consecutive numbers to be picked, this would cover the cases you mentioned earlier, correct?

Comment: Replacing each $5$ in my answer with $5 \choose i$ where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $4$, I get $9$ as the total number of ways. It still looks like there's something wrong.

Comment: I didn't have a nice answer, so I came back to see if anyone else did; oh well. Anyway, @jd94, your last comment doesn't make sense. $\binom{5}{3} 3!/3$ doesn't count anything straightforward in this scenario. (What is your interpretation? The analogy doesn't extend from pairs to triplets, since you can't fit two distinct triplets in five seats.) If this doesn't make sense, then I would start by listing out each permutation (01234, 01243, ...) and list which ones you want to eliminate with each term in your solution above. Check whether the two numbers agree. This will be easier with $n=4$.

Comment: I realized that it may be helpful to think about the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of 5 while doing the counting.  The terms in the partition refer to groups of a certain length (i.e., $3+1+1$ means a sequential group of length 3, followed by two individuals that are not sequential).  But it is still not straightforward.  The problem is that even if you look at a particular partition, you have to take other partitions into account.  An extreme example is $4+1$, which is impossible because it always reduces to a sequential group of length 5.

Comment: Another approach is to try to use a recurrence relation on the number of people/seats, $n$.  I had thought about this a couple of days ago when you posted the question.  But if you remove one element from a valid circular configuration of $n$ elements, you don't necessarily end up with a valid configuration of $n-1$ elements, so it is hard to relate the case of $n$ to $n-1$.  it is a little bit easier for linear configurations, but then at the end you have to find a way to close the linear configuration into a circle, and I couldn't find a good argument for doing that either.